# Emergency Help: Running "bundle exec rake assets:precompile" has caused server to crash EACESS Error Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, server, rake

(I'm in an intern in a bit of hot water right now & would highly appreciate some help if possible. Thank you so much)

I've been working on a subsection of a development server environment using Ruby on Rails as its primary development language and a javascript file I wrote was not compiling or working on the server. So I saw someone suggest running bundle exec rake assets:precompile might help solve the problem.

Unfortunately, the entire server now is non functional, whenever I try to navigate anywhere I get the below error:

Errno::EACCES in XXXXXXXXXXXX

Showing /srv/www/XXXX/app/views/ where line #12 raised:

Permission denied @ apply2files - /srv/www/XXXXXXx/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/2g/2gWR-F_kIEZpPaAYFSZfK9XNrXA6JBy0NB0aKGrSfE0.cache

I've been tempted to clear the cache folder which I suspect already occurred in the above command but I'm too afraid to do anything else until I get some clarity as to whats going on.

Memcached, redis, & sidekiq are at play here too: is there anyway I can rollback the action of this command? I've tried restarting the server to no joy, re-pushing the git branch makes no difference. IF anyone at all has any suggestions as to what I can try to do to reverse this I would be eternally grateful.

I have user permission to clear the cache but am worried it'll interfere elsewhere

Thank you so much

Comment: Seems like when you ran the command, it changed the directory's owner/permission. It's trying to write/read in the directory and failing. Try changing the owner of the `tmp/` directory using `chown` to the user Ruby is running as.

Comment: ANSWER: If anyone else ever runs into this horrific problem the solution is :  bundle rake exec tmp:clear cache

Comment: Thanks Amir, just found the answer there :)